# Can't resolve module (not found) in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't believe that I'm asking an obvious question, but I still get the error in console log.

Console says that it can't find the module in the directory, but I've checked at least 10 times for typos. Anyways, here's the component code.

I want to render **Header** in root

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Header from './src/components/header/header'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Header/>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the `Header` component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import navBar from './src/components/header/navBar'
import './src/css/header.css'

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return {
            <div>
             <div id="particles-js"></div>
             <navBar/>
             <Title/>
          </div>
        };
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Header/>, document.getElementById('header'));
```

I've checked at least 10 times that the module is at this location `./src/components/header/header`, and it is (folder "header" contains "header.js").

Yet, React still throws this error:

**Failed to compile**

`./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './src/components/header/header' in '/home/wiseman/Desktop/React_Components/github-portfolio/src'`

**npm test** says the same thing.

Comment: add `export default Header;` on your 'header file'

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: It seems you need `import Header from './components/header/header'` w/o src. File path is relative to importing file path. Then you need to export `Header` from `header.js` and fix `App.render` method.

Comment: If I take the `components` folder outside from `src` folder, then it tells me that I need to modify the `node_modules` files, which is not my attention.

Comment: You don't need to move anything. You have incorrect relative path. If you are importing inside './src/app.js' it should be `import smth from './components/header/header'` Same for this line `import navBar from './src/components/header/navBar'` it should be relative to current path `import navBar from './navBar'`

Comment: This may or may not be relevant for this situation but also be mindful of case in your directory paths.  I had a situation where my local directories were lower case, but in prod they were upper.  I had to completely wipe away my local structure and clone from prod to fix it, otherwise I was going to spend a lot of time refactoring directory names.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

The way we usually use `import` is based on relative path.

`.` and `..` are similar to how we use to navigate in `terminal` like `cd ..` to go out of directory and `mv ~/file .` to move a `file` to current directory.

```
my-app/
  node_modules/
  package.json
  src/
    containers/card.js
    components/header.js
    App.js
    index.js
```

In your case, `App.js` is in `src/` directory while `header.js` is in `src/components`. To `import` you would do `import Header from './components/header'`. This roughly translate to in my current directory, find the components folder that contain a header file.

Now, if from `header.js`, you need to `import` something from `card`, you would do this. `import Card from '../containers/card'`. This translate to, move out of my current directory, look for a folder name containers that have a card file.

As for `import React, { Component } from 'react'`, this does not start with a `./` or `../` or `/` therefore node will start looking for the module in the `node_modules` in a specific order till `react` is found. For a more detail understanding, it can be read [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules).

Answer (score 41):

If you create an application with react-create-app, don't forget set environment variable:

```
NODE_PATH=./src
```

Or add to `.env` file to your root folder;

Comment: This is the one the solved for me. I added a simple `App.css` to `src/` and did `import App.css`. But that gave me the error of the question. This answer solved the issue.

Comment: I thought I was crazy my react app wasn't working as expected and I just paste this environment variable and it just works... The thing is why it doesn't come with this file already... I don't get it, if react spends twelve minutes downloading a bunch of dependencies why it doesn't come with these file.

Answer (score 34):

Deleted the package-lock.json file & then ran

```
npm install
```

[Read further](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6695)

Comment: Thank you so much, I had the following error: Module not found: Can't resolve... TextInput and your solution solved it

Comment: This is good idea to do on any project we get from outside.

Answer (score 29):

in my case, The error message was

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/components/body
```

While everything was in the correct directory.

I found that renaming `body.jsx` to `body.js` resolve the issue!

So I added this code in `webpack.config.js` to resolve `jsx` as `js`

```
 module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

And then build error gone!

Comment: Indeed, in my case I had forgotten to put ".tsx" in the extensions array.

Answer (score 16):

Adding `NODE_PATH` as environment variable in `.env` is deprecated and is replaced by adding `"baseUrl": "./src"`, to `compilerOptions` in `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json`.

**[Reference](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/6656)**

Answer (score 11):

I solved by putting the file extension

```
import MyComponent from "src/components/MyComponent";
```

to

```
import MyComponent from "src/components/MyComponent.tsx";
```

Comment: ? TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.tsx' extension.

Comment: [This is the actual fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62539344/542251) for this

Answer (score 9):

I think its the double use of header. I just tried something similar myself and also caused issues. I capitalized my component file to match the others and it worked.

```
import Header from './src/components/header/header';
```

Should be

```
import Header from './src/components/header/Header';
```

Comment: I hate this gave me the answer because I havd the same folder structure and instead of doing `./components/header/header` I was doing `./components/header` ... I am too old for those kinda mistakes lolol

Comment: @Chris what's up with that? I also fixed mine doing the same. So confusing. Anyone with a simple explanation?

Answer (score 9):

There is a better way you can handle the import of modules in your React App.
Consider doing this:

> Add a `jsconfig.json` file to your base folder. That is the same folder containing your package.json. Next define your base URL imports in it:

```
//jsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

Now rather than calling `../../` you can easily do this instead:

```
import navBar from 'components/header/navBar'
import 'css/header.css'
```

Notice that 'components/' is different from '../components/'

It's neater this way.

But if you want to import files in the same directory you can do this also:

```
import logo from './logo.svg'
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.

Cause:

```
import HomeComponent from "components/HomeComponent";
```

Solution:

```
import HomeComponent from "./components/HomeComponent";
```

**NOTE:** `./` was before components. You can read @Zac Kwan's post above on how to use `import`

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue when I created a new react app, I tried all options in https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2534  but it didn't help. I had to change the port for the new app and then it worked. By default, apps use the port 3000.I changed the port to 8001 in package.json as follows:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8001 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using create-react-app, and have just added typescript to it, check whether a `tsconfig.json` has been auto-generated for you. The CRA docs say that it should be, but [there seems to be a bug](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10951) at the moment where it is not being generated.

If the `tsconfig.json` is missing, there's a few ways to create one yourself.

- Copy one off the internet or from another repo
- `npx tsc --init`
- Create a fresh project somewhere else using `npx create-react-app my-ts-proj --template typescript` and then copy the tsconfig over from there

Answer (score 2):

You can try to execute 'npm install' in the app folder. This might also solve the problem. It worked for me.

Comment: specifically if the package was installed with another user previously. ie: check access privileges of files/folders

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue from auto-importing a component, no type or webpack config issues.

What fixed it was changing the import from relative to the app root directory to relative to the file:

```
import MyComponent from "src/components/MyComponent";
```

to

```
import MyComponent from "../components/MyComponent";
```

If you're getting this from Visual Studio Code auto-importing via the shortest route, you can change it so it imports **relatively**. By going here:

menu *File → Preferences → Settings → User Settings*,

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change import Header from '**.**/src/components/header/header' to

import Header from '**..**/src/components/header/header'

Answer (score 0):

replace `ReactDOM.render(<Header/>, document.getElementById('header'));`  by `export default Header` in Header.js

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me just (./) no need src here

```
import Header from './components/header/header'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be importing .tsx file inside a .js file. Ensure that if you are working on a javascript source, you have extensions .js or .jsx not .tsx :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, with [next.js](/questions/tagged/next.js) framework I got the same error after deleting the "loading.tsx" (not imported anywhere). Just in case you have similar situation. I resolved by removing the `.next/cache/webpack`. Or remove the entire `.next/cache` directory

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have solved this by now but let me add it for future reference.
I did encounter the same issue and my issue was on renaming and path refernce.
Have a look at this, code when getting the error

```
import Account from "./account";
```

The problem is with path reference and naming

Here is the correct code

```
import Account from "./pages/dashboard/Account";
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to be in project folder, if you are in `src` or `public` you have to come out of those folders. Suppose your react-project name is 'hello-react' then `cd hello-react`

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem and I resolved it.
See if your `index.js` file is in `src` folder, then what ever file you are importing, the folder containing that must also be inside the src folder.

That means if your components folder is outside the `src` folder, just drag it inside the `src` folder in your editor because the files outside of `src` folder are not imported.

Then you shall be able to import using `./components/header/header`(in this case)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

For me, I had the input correct but `npm start` can be buggy (at least using it with Hyper terminal on Windows and Linux). If I move files to different folders, npm start doesn't pick up on these changes. I need to cancel npm start process, make the move, save and then run `npm start` and it will see the files now.

Answer (score -3):

In my case I rename a component file, an VS Code add the below line of code for me:

```
import React, { Component } from "./node_modules/react";
```

So I fixed by removing the: `./node_modules/`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

I think it may help you-

Read your error carefully-./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './src/components/header/header' in '/home/wiseman/Desktop/React_Components/github-portfolio/src'

just write- ./header/header instead ./src/components/header/header in App.js

if it doesnt work try to change header file name may be head

Answer (score -4):

Check for the import statements.It should be ended with semicolon. If you miss any, you will get this error.

Also check whether following import statement added in you component.

import { threadId } from 'worker_threads';

If so remove that line. It works for me.