# Fix folder structure errors in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to React and had everything working before I decided to organize my code in folders and subfolders. Right now I'm getting this Module not found, but it isn't the "Can't resolve 'react' which there were some answers for. Maybe some of you might know this silly thing. Thanks in advance! I really appreciate it!

Here is the Compile error
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BhaD.png)

Here is an image of my folder [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAFV5.png)

Here is my **Header.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Header/CSS/Header.css';

// Class will consist of Header design and structure
const Header = (props) => {
    return (
        <header className="App-header">
        <div className="container">
            <button className="btn">
              <span>About</span>
            </button>
            <button className="btn">
              <span>Experience</span>
            </button>
            <button className="btn">
              <span>Education</span>
            </button>
            <button className="btn">
              <span>Projects</span>
            </button>
            <button className="btn">
              <span>Contact</span>
            </button>
          </div>
      </header>
    )
};

export default Header;
```

Here is my **Header.css**

```
/* 
  ========================
   HEADER Component
   CSS for the header   
  ========================
  */

 .App-header {
     background-color: black;
     min-height: 05vh;
     display: inline-flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
     color: white;
     padding: 5vw;
 }

 /* 
  ========================
   HEADER BUTTONS
  ========================
  */

 .container {
     display: inline-flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
 }

 .btn {
     margin: 5%;
     display: inline-flex;
 }
```

Here is my **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header/js/Header.js';
/* 
  ========================================
   App class
   Where everything is put together
   eg. Skeleton of my website
  ========================================
*/
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where is your `Header.css` file? You may be pointing it to the wrong path.

Comment: It looks like it will be `import './CSS/Header.css';`

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro I added an image of my folder structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't resolve module (not found) in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439205/cant-resolve-module-not-found-in-react-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```js
import '../CSS/Header.css';
```

`../` (2 dot) goes back one folder, and `./` (1 dot) stay in the same directory.

Since your structure looks like this:

```
. src
.. Header
.... CSS
...... Header.css
.... JS
...... Header.js
```

Using `../` inside `Header.js`, will take you to the `Header` folder.

Comment: I get this -> ./src/Header/JS/Header.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './CSS/Header.css' in 'C:\Users\leosu\Desktop\my-website\src\Header\JS'

Comment: My bad, it was a typo. Use 2 dots. I updated the answer.

Comment: Now I get this -  **./src/Header/JS/Header.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './node_modules/react' in 'C:\Users\leosu\Desktop\my-website\src\Header\JS'**

Comment: No problem! Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your import route to `import '.. /Header/CSS/Header.css';`

Comment: If I do that, I get this
./src/Header/JS/Header.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../Header/CSS/Header.css' in 'C:\Users\leosu\Desktop\my-website\src\Header\JS'

Answer (score 0):

Within your config files, such as webpack config or Babel, you will need to use a OS agnostic method of finding files because:

Windows uses `\` and everything else uses `/`

So require Node's built in `path` module

```
const path = require('path')
```

And in your config files use `path` and `__dirname`

```
// "target": "./dist"
"target": path(__dirname, '/dist')
```