# How do i import my file to app.js using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I'v been trying to import a javascript file to app.js found in create-react-app package. I used this code to import my file :

note:my file is located in a folder called components where you find the folder Navigation and its in that folder.

`import script from './components/Navigation/script`;

and i exported the file using :

```
export default App;
```

but in my terminal i got an error saying

`Module not found :  cant resolve'./components/Navigation/script'`

Could someone please tell me how i can fix this error.
Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: are you sure exported file properly? something like this ----  export default script;

Comment: `app.js` and `components` must be in the same folder. Are you sure they are in the same directory? Perhaps try [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439205/cant-resolve-module-not-found-in-react-js). It might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the syntax wrong.

```
import script from './components/Navigation/script;
```

actually imports the default export from script.js

```
export default function() {}
```

You can also import named exports like this:

```
import {something} from "./script.js"
```

Which imports

```
const something = 42;
export something;
```

**I guess you could import js(and css) files with**

```
import "./scripts.js" //or import "./style.css"
```

But you generally want to export individual functions, values etc.

You can also import everything from a module like this

```
import * as React from "react";
```

But create-react-app configuration allows you to use this as

```
import React from "react"; //Internally equals to import * as React from "react";
```