# React - Module parse failed: Unexpected Token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

My first time using react, so apologies if I'm doing something obvious and incredibly wrong.  That said, I've read up on several similar-seeming bugs on here and on github and I can't find anything that works for mine.  Here's the full error message:

```
ERROR in ./src/frontend/src/components/App.js 6:15
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| class App extends Component{
|     render() {
>         return <h1>React App</h1>
|     }
| }
 @ ./src/frontend/src/index.js 1:0-35
```

The full code from which that error message was drawn:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return <h1>React App</h1>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I feel like something is wrong with my webpack-config.js, but I copied that directly from a tutorial I was using so I'm not sure why it would be wrong.  Here it is, for reference:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And here are my package dependencies from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
```

And finally my .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties".js]
}
```

I really have no idea what's going on, so any help would be much appreciated.  Please let me know if I left out any relevant info that could be helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error comes from this line: `return <h1>React App</h1>`, because `<h1>...</h1>` is not valid javascript. Even if rename this is would be parsed as vanilla js and not jsx, because of your `webpack-config.js`, so there are multiple things you should do to fix it:

1. Rename `App.js` to `App.jsx`,
2. Update `test: /\.js$/,` to `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,` in webpack-config.js
3. I think there is also an error in your `.babelrc`: you don't want that `.js` there, after `"transform-class-properties"`.
4. Rename `webpack-config.js` to `webpack.config.js`

Here is a tutorial that shows this: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/. Also, you could use https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app that simplifies all of this and provides a great starting config.

Comment: Thanks so much. Following those steps fixed the error I posted about.  But the same error is now being generated by the next line:
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
If you have any insight as to why this has happened, I would really appreciate it. Otherwise, thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you update the question with the new error? Is it literally the same error just pointing to a different line?

Comment: I found the error.  I had named the webpack config file "webpack-config.js" but it was actually supposed to be "webpack.config.js"  
Really beyond stupid but at least it was an easy fix once I realized.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad it worked and added that to my answer to keep the info ordered. If everything worked could you accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Added this code in webpack.config.js to resolve jsx as js.
Visit [Can't resolve module (not found) in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439205/cant-resolve-module-not-found-in-react-js)

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
};
```