# Facing issue to getting movie list at the time of fetching data from TMDB sites

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am facing some problem:

> ```
> ./src/Banner.js 73:11
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (73:11)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> |       columnNumber: 13
> |     }
> >   }, movie?.title || movie?.name || movie?.original_name), /*#_PURE_*/React.createElement("div", {
> |     className: "banner_buttons",
> |     __self: this,
> ```

My code is:

```
import axios from './Myaxios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './css/banner.css'
import userrequests from './Request'

function Banner() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(userrequests.fetchNetflixOriginals);
      setMovie(request.data.results[Math.floor(Math.random() * request.data.results.length-1)])
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])
      
  return (
    <div className="banner" >
      <div className='banner_content'>
        <h1 className='banner_title'>
          {movie?.title || movie?.name || movie?.original_name}
        </h1>

        <div className='banner_buttons'>
          <button>Play</button>
          <button>My List</button>
        </div>

        <div className='banner_description'>
          <p>
            {movie?.overview}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Banner
```

What I do for this

Comment: The code looks OK. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769414/react-module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loade

Comment: Does your transpiler differentiate between *.js and *.jsx files? Does the file need to be named `Banner.jsx` for it to transpile JSX correctly? Do you need to update your configurations like the linked duplicate suggestion? Can you share how you've configured your project?

Comment: yeah, here is my github repo please see what is issue. And what I do???? 
https://github.com/mdehteshamcoder/clone-netflix-a-.git