# React components folder not detected

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend

I'm getting the following error in react. It appears to be bit simillar to this one.

[Can't resolve module (not found) in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439205/cant-resolve-module-not-found-in-react-js)

I tried the renaming .jsx files to .js files and rechecked the import path as given in the above question, but they still give me the same error. Here is an image of what my error looks like.[vs code error and folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZvlo.png)

Code of my App.js file is given below.

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import {ListSalaryComponent,CreateSalaryComponent,UpdateSalaryComponent,ListItemComponent,CreateItem,UpdateItemComponent,CreateMachineComponent,ListMachineComponent,UpdateMachineComponent} from './components';
import LogIn from './pages/LogIn';
import QuotationRequest from './pages/QuotationRequest';
import QuotationProcessIntro from './pages/QuotationProcessIntro';
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Switch>

          <Route exact path='/viewInvoice/:invoice_id'>
            <ViewInvoiceComponent />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/salaries" >
    <ListSalaryComponent/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/add-salary">
          <CreateSalaryComponent/>
          </Route>
        <Route path="/update-salary/:id">
          <UpdateSalaryComponent/>
        </Route>
        <Route  path="/listitems"><ListItemComponent/></Route>
                  <Route  path="/items" ><ListItemComponent /></Route>
                  <Route  path="/add-item"><CreateItem/></Route>
                  <Route path="/edit-item/:item_code"> <UpdateItemComponent/></Route>

                
                <Route path="/machine-list" ><ListMachineComponent/></Route>
                <Route path="/machines"> <ListMachineComponent/></Route>
                <Route path="/add-Machine"> <CreateMachineComponent/></Route>
                <Route path="/update-Machine/:id"> <UpdateMachineComponent/></Route> 
              
      </Switch>
      </Router>
      <QuotationRequest></QuotationRequest>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the complete error message I get.

> ERROR in ./src/App.js 6:0-220
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/' in 'D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src'
> resolve './components/' in 'D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src'
> Parsed request is a directory
> using description file: D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src)
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> using description file: D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/components)
> as directory
> existing directory D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src\components
> using description file: D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/components)
> using path: D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src\components\index
> using description file: D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\package.json (relative path: ./src/components/index)
> no extension
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src\components\index doesn't exist
> .web.mjs
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src\components\index.web.mjs doesn't exist
> .mjs
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src\components\index.mjs doesn't exist
> .web.js
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src\components\index.web.js doesn't exist
> .js
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src\components\index.js doesn't exist
> .json
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src\components\index.json doesn't exist
> .web.jsx
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src\components\index.web.jsx doesn't exist
> .jsx
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
> D:\SLIIT\Y2S2\ITP\Project\Project Code\itp_project_group_b1-wd_b01_itp_g16\Development\itp-frontend\src\components\index.jsx doesn't exist
> @ ./src/index.js 8:0-24 12:33-36

webpack 5.70.0 compiled with 1 error and 1 warning in 676 ms

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that produces the error you are asking about. Then show what fixes you tried and what the results were. Just saying "they didn't work for me" isn't enough information for us to help you.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This is a good start. The inconvenience here is all yours, so don't apologize. To get the help you want faster, you should include as much as you think we need to answer your question. For example, what is the exact error message?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the error. You can refer the image too.

Comment: Seems you don't have an index.js in the "components" folder

Comment: @Pipe It solved the issue. Thanks.