# Module not found Error or Unable to load image in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, runtime-error

This is my project structure :

```
src
 -assets
     fut.png
 -components
    -admin_dashboard
        Sidebar.js
 -App.js
 -pages
    Dashboard.js
```

I wanted to load the image `fut.png` from the file `Sidebar.js`. As it was not loading when calling with its relative path such as `<img src={"../assets/fut.png"}/>` , I tried `<img src={require("../assets/fut.png")}/>` - this results in this error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/fut.png' in 'D:\Users [DONT DELETE]\react js\fut_test\src\components\admin_dashboard'`

First am rendering the `Dashboard` component from `App.js`. Then rendering the `Sidebar` component from `Dashboard.js`.Thus the call to `Sidebar.js` file is initiated.

Actually i tried loading the image by putting even in the same folder of `Sidebar.js` file accessing it as `<img src={"fut.png"}/>` .Even that didn't load the image. How can i fix this?

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React from 'react'

function Sidebar(){

return(
        <div className="flex">
<img src={require("../assets/future_ik.png")} />
</div>
); 
     }

export default Sidebar
```

I have already gone through these links:

1. [Can't resolve module (not found) in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439205/cant-resolve-module-not-found-in-react-js)
2. [React won't load local images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images)

But still don't know how to solve this in my case. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
import logo from './logo.jpeg'; // with import

const logo = require('./logo.jpeg'); // with require

<img src={logo} />
```

you could also try with another image in jpeg format to see if it does not come from the

basically it gives something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.svg';
export default class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="logo">
          <img src={logo} width="100" height="50" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```