# React can't access components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to react and I'm having trouble separating my components into different files.

I get this error

**ERROR in ./src/App.js 5:0-34
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /components/map which falls outside of the project src/ directory.**

I have an App.js file where I am trying to access my map component.

```
import Map from "/components/map"

import './App.css';
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript, MarkerF } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "Not Showing StackOverflow",
  authDomain: "Not Showing StackOverflow",
  projectId: "Not Showing StackOverflow",
  storageBucket: "Not Showing StackOverflow",
  messagingSenderId: "Not Showing StackOverflow",
  appId: "Not Showing StackOverflow",
  measurementId: "Not Showing StackOverflow"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

function App() {
  const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
    libraries: ["places"],
  });

  if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>
  return(
    <div className="Page">
      <Map />
    </div>
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

and I have a file called map.tsx

```
import { useState, useMemo, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import {
    GoogleMap,
    Marker,
    DirectionsRenderer,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";
//import Places from "./places";
//import Distance from "./distance";
import React from "react";

type LatLngLiteral = google.maps.LatLngLiteral;
type DirectionsResult = google.maps.DirectionsResult;
type MapOptions = google.maps.MapOptions;

export default function Map() { 
    return <GoogleMap 
      zoom={10} 
      center={{ lat: 44, lng: -80 }} 
      mapContainerClassName='map-container'
    > </GoogleMap>
  }
```

The components folder is inside the src folder so not sure what the error is
It's probably something simple I just don't know

Another note I created this app with create-react-app and I added a file .env and put `NODE_PATH=./src` from a suggestion here [Can't resolve module (not found) in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439205/cant-resolve-module-not-found-in-react-js) but it is still not working

My file structure

My-App-Name/

-src/

--components/

---map.tsx

--App.js

-.env

Comment: Did you make sure to put `/components/map` at the root of your filesystem like you're specifying?

Comment: It is My-App-Name/src/components/map

Comment: So you need to move it to the root of your filesystem like you specified.

Comment: It is located under the src directory so that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to explicitly write the filename and type like this

```
import Map from "./components/map.tsx"
```

Now it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bruh stupid bot. It was literally as simple as adding file extension 

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the first line of you file should be:
import Map from "./components/map"

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work

Comment: I added the file extension and it works

Answer (score 0):

added .tsx after at end of import and that work for me